# SVNIgnore for Android Studio Projects

Tags: android, svn, android-studio, svnignore

I try to import my Android Studio project on different machines and wondering which project files are realy needed. For example the .idea or .gradle directories. I won't to much trash in my svn repo. Can someone tell my more about required files for Android Studio projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep these files in your root project

- app folder (tough ignore the build folder inside it recursively, it's a big waste of space)
- gradle
- .gitignore if you are using GIT
- build.gradle
- gradle.properties if you want to have the same configuration on all of your pc's. You need to cinfugure it first tough.
- gradlew
- gradlew.bat
- settings.gradle

Anything else that is not on the list and was not created by you, can be ignored

Make sure you ignore these by file name wildcard. This is the garbage created by macs and windows machines.

- .DS_Store
- desktop.ini
- Thumbs.db
- *.iml (garbage created by Android studio)

Answer (score -1):

I truely recomend you to use git in Android Studio, the integration is awesome and it`s so easy to use. It select the files u need for you and have really good tools for merge files.

Comment: I know the benefit by using git but i use a private svn and will not switch at the moment.